# NestedPath type generator, type symbol is not assignable to string | number... using keyof T

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

As an exercise I am trying to write a code that will generate the correct type to use as path to index an object, here's an example :

```
type Path = ...

interface HouseAddress {
  street: string;
  number: number;
  city: string;
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  house?: HouseAddress;
  child: Person;
}

const col: Path<Person> = "name"; //ok
const col: Path<Person> = "house.street"; //ok
const col: Path<Person> = "cat.name"; // not ok
```

After tinkering with Typescript I wrote this code

```
type What<T> = T extends never ? never : keyof T;

type NestedPath<T, Key extends keyof T> = Key extends string
  ? T[Key] extends Record<string, any> | undefined
    ? `${Key}.${What<T[Key]>}` 
    | `${Key}.${NestedPath<T[Key], keyof T[Key]>}`
    : never
  : never;
```

Now everything works as intended but I have no idea why ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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))

```
const col: Path<Person> = "name"; //ok
const col: Path<Person> = "house.street"; //ok
const col: Path<Person> = "cat.name"; // not ok
```

If i don't use the `What` type and instead write `Exclude<keyof T[Key], symbol>` or `keyof T[Key] & string` then `const col: Path<Person> = "house.city"` does not compile.

My question is : why does using the `What` type "works" when Excluding symbol from keyof T does not ?

Comment: what if the object key value is an array?

Comment: Could you please [edit] to make sure the post asks a single, well-defined question?  Right now it looks like you're asking two questions about why something is happening, plus an edit about how trying to fix it.  If you're really trying to implement something then maybe ask directly how to implement it; otherwise, please pick a particular thing that you want explained and ask that.  Right now I don't know how to answer this without writing a book-length answer covering too many topics

Comment: Like, if we're just trying to implement it, I'd do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mb3DBW) and move on.  If we're really trying to debug various failed attempts or understand trial-and-error successes then that's a lot more forensic analysis needed.

Comment: @jaclz thank you for your comments, i have edited my post to ask a single question. Since i do this as an exercise to practice my typescript i'm not asking for an "implementation only" answer, while i thank you for your solution and i understand why it works, i would like to know and understand where i went wrong, after reading the code you provided i don't even understand how my solution could have ever "worked"

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/NVOvqm